# Cannot Create Variable Activity on data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create data factory resources using python and I am getting error while calling few classes

example- here I am trying to create "Set Variable Activity" but I am getting error

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.setvariableactivity?view=azure-python

**Error Message**

> NameError: name 'SetVariableActivity' is not defined

**Code**

```
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

variable_name = 'vGetDate'
var_activity = SetVariableActivity(name = 'Get Date',variable_name= variable_name, value = '@utcnow()' )
```

I am getting NameError with DatasetFolder Class as well. I am not sure what went wrong, I thought I have imported all the required libraries and I am using on 3.7 v

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code on my side, it works fine, please try the same version of the libraries with me.

```
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-mgmt-datafactory==0.9.0
```

My sample creates a pipeline with the `Set variable` activity:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

subscription_id = '<subscription-id>'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='<client-id>', secret='<client-secret>', tenant='<tenant-id>')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

variable_name = 'vGetDate'
var_activity = SetVariableActivity(name = 'Get Date',variable_name= variable_name, value = '@utcnow()' )

rg_name = '<resource-group-name>'
df_name = 'joyfactory'
p_name = 'Pipeline123'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(
    activities=[var_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
print(p)
```

[image]

**Check in the portal**:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks for your inputs, it was version issue on my side.. azure-mgmt-datafactory was on 0.6.0